# How to create a python virtual environment that has its directory as absolute root

Tags: python-3.x, macos, virtualenv

For a few reasons, I need to have the following path on my macbook:

```
/home/foo/bar
```

and `/home/` directory is reserved by the os as far as I know, so is there some way to create some isolated virtual env that does not have access to the host env?

Example: `virtualenv --isolate env_foo`

Or better maybe something to do enable creating new folders in `/home/`?

Comment: Is this for a daemon of some sort?  Are you sure you're not supposed to create a dedicated user `foo` to run it instead?

Comment: @wim in order to better understand the problem, please check my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732723/build-tensorflow-pip-package-on-2-different-platformsubuntu-osx-catalina